# getIntent helper class

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to setup an Intent helper class called "GetIntents". My problem is, how would I call my GetIntents helper class from an activity?

Here is my GetIntents helper class:

```
 public class GetIntents extends Intent {

public static Intent i;

public static String username = i.getExtras().getString("uid");
public static String password = i.getExtras().getString("pwd");
public static String firstName = i.getExtras().getString("firstName");
public static String lastName = i.getExtras().getString("lastName");
public static String lastLatitudeUpdate = i.getExtras().getString("lastLatitudeUpdate");

public static int checkedin = i.getExtras().getInt("checkedin");
public static int Minute = i.getExtras().getInt("Minute");
public static int Hour = i.getExtras().getInt("Hour");

}
```

Now im not sure how I would be able to call it from my activity. So far I have tried:

```
 GetIntents intent = new GetIntents();
 intent.getIntent();
```

I've also tried a couple other ways, but no luck. Any suggestions on what I could try?

My logs:

```
 06-21 11:26:18.249: D/AndroidRuntime(8978): Shutting down VM

 06-21 11:26:18.249: W/dalvikvm(8978): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.jetdelivery.mobile/com.jetdelivery.mobile.screen1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
  06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at com.jetdelivery.mobile.GetIntentHelper.getDataModel(GetIntentHelper.java:9)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at com.jetdelivery.mobile.screen1.<init>(screen1.java:66)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
 06-21 11:26:18.253: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your help. I have decided to go another route instead of using a helper class.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
username = i.getExtras().getString("uid");
password = i.getExtras().getString("pwd");
firstName = i.getExtras().getString("firstName");
lastName = i.getExtras().getString("lastName");
lastLatitudeUpdate = i.getExtras().getString("lastLatitudeUpdate");
checkedin = i.getExtras().getInt("checkedin");
Minute = i.getExtras().getInt("Minute");
Hour = i.getExtras().getInt("Hour");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it a few ways.
Your GetIntent class should just be a wrapper for a bunch of static methods.
And your function calls will look something like

```
String username = GetIntent.getUsername(intent);
```

Or you can pass in the intent when you create the class

```
GetIntent mIntent = new GetIntent(getIntent());
```

Either way your still going to have to pass an Intent and you won't be able to statically assign the values into your member function, unless this is a innerclass. But if your doing that than why even have the Class in the first place when you can use us the variables.

Comment: I get majority of what you are saying (sorry, still learning) so what you are saying, its kind of redundant if I were to use static in a helper class, but rather use static from an inner class so I can call it anywhere?

Comment: I think you may have that backwards. First you have two options, static methods or not. If your using static methods, then you do not need to create an instance of your class. As a side effect, since the methods are static they won't have an instance of intent laying around (which is why you need to give it one). The other route is to new up your class and pass it in an intent to hold onto. Then you make your method calls using your variable to get the information you want out. Those methods will just be making the getExtra() operations on the intent you gave it when you newed it up.

Comment: Thank you clearing that up Frank! I have decided to just go another route instead of using a helper class for my intents.

Comment: No problem. Just upvote and/or accept anything that helped you. I know the other guys spent some time writing those answers too.

Answer (score 1):

Yer kinda close.

Create a java class called DataModel like so :

```
public class DataModel {
        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getPassword() {
            return password;
        }

        public void setPassword(String password) {
            this.password = password;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public String getLastLatitudeUpdate() {
            return lastLatitudeUpdate;
        }

        public void setLastLatitudeUpdate(String lastLatitudeUpdate) {
            this.lastLatitudeUpdate = lastLatitudeUpdate;
        }

        public int getCheckedin() {
            return checkedin;
        }

        public void setCheckedin(int checkedin) {
            this.checkedin = checkedin;
        }

        public int getMinute() {
            return Minute;
        }

        public void setMinute(int minute) {
            Minute = minute;
        }

        public int getHour() {
            return Hour;
        }

        public void setHour(int hour) {
            Hour = hour;
        }

        private String username;
        private String password;
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String lastLatitudeUpdate;

        private int checkedin;
        private int Minute;
        private int Hour;
    }
```

then create another class called GetIntentHelper, like so

```
public class GetIntentHelper {

    public static DataModel getDataModel(Intent i) {
        DataModel m = new DataModel();
        m.setUsername(i.getExtras().getString("uid"));
        m.setPassword(i.getExtras().getString("pwd"));
        m.setFirstName(i.getExtras().getString("firstName"));
        m.setLastName(i.getExtras().getString("lastName"));
        m.setLastLatitudeUpdate(i.getExtras().getString("lastLatitudeUpdate"));

        m.setCheckedin(i.getExtras().getInt("checkedin"));
        m.setMinute(i.getExtras().getInt("Minute"));
        m.setHour(i.getExtras().getInt("Hour"));

        return m;
    }
}
```

As for usage, in your activity, call:

```
DataModel  mydata = GetIntentHelper.getDataModel(myIntent);
```

which will return an instance of DataModel called mydata with your data all nice and neat for you to play with.

Comment: I've tried what you suggested and I am getting a force close. Ill put up the logs right now so you can see it. Also, thanks for taking the time to help me.